# Accessing props in vue component data function

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

I am passing a props to a component:

```html
    <template>
       {{messageId}}
       // other html code
    </template>
    
    <script>
       export default {
          props: ['messageId'],
          data: function(){
             var theData={
                // below line gives ReferenceError messageId is not defined
                somevar: messageId,
                // other object attributes
             }
          }
       }
    </script>
```

In above code, I have commented the line that gives the error. If I remove that line, it works as normal and template renders properly (and I can see the expected value of {{messageId}} as well). Hence the logic to pass data is correct.

It seems that the way to access the `messageId` in data() is wrong.
So how do I access the props `messageId` in data?

Comment: `this.messageId`

Comment: Also, your data function needs to return the data object.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

From the `data()` method, you can reference the component's properties using `this`.

So in your case:

```
data: function() {
  var theData = {
    somevar: this.messageId,
    // other object attributes
  }

  return theData;
}
```

Comment: data () {
               return {
                   open: this.open,
                   close: this.close
                 }
              },

Answer (score 71):

EDIT: According to Ryans posts it is possible to reference the instance with an arrow function like this:

```
data: (instance) => ({
  somevar: instance.messageId 
}),
```

PREVIOUS POST:

Note that this does not work if you are using an arrow function for assigning your data:

```
data: () => ({
  somevar: this.messageId // undefined
}),
```

Because `this` will not point to the component. Instead, use a plain function:

```
data: function() {
  return { somevar: this.messageId }
},
```

or using ES6 object method shorthand as Siva Tumma suggested:

```
data() {
    return { somevar: this.messageId }
}
```

Comment: Instead why not use `data() {..}`

Comment: I got burned by this once. It's a subtle difference but switching the function from arrow to data() {return {}} does the trick. Thanks mufasa.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was looking for it.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.

Comment: You can use an arrow function actually— the first argument will be a reference to the instance. `data: vm => ({ somevar: vm.messageId })`

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but this answer solved an issue I just ran into. My understanding (albeit probably wrong now obviously) was that all three function declarations are the same, just difference in syntactic sugar. I'll research this but if someone want to drop a hint I won't complain.

Comment: @jvndev Yes, the two bottom ones are the same and the top one is an arrow function which handles the context differently

Answer (score 16):

To assign a data property equal to a props, you can use watcher, as following:

```
<script>
   export default {
      props: ['messageId'],
      data: function(){
         var theData={
            somevar: "",
            // other object attributes
         }
      },
      watch: {
        messageId: function(newVal) { 
           this.somevar = newVal
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Or use a `computed`

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, that also can be done, but If you want to update the data variable, than you have to use computed with getter.

Comment: I mean you should replace the data item with a computed, if `somevar` is never assigned by anything but the watcher.

Comment: @RoyJ Why is that needed?

Comment: It makes the code clearer. A computed is effectively a watcher plus a data item.

Comment: I will completely agree with you on [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41646264/1610034).

Comment: this will trigger an input event when you have an input v-model that data

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 3):

as @Saurabh described, I want to add more details.

If you are rendering a `Child` component, and want to set the `data` variables by `props`, you have to use both `this` and `watch` functions:

## Step1. use `this` to access the `props` variables.

```
<script>
export default {

    data () {
      id: 0
    },
    
  
    props: ['propId'],
    methods: {
      init() { 
        this.id = this.propId  // step1. assign propId to id
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

## Step2. watch the `props` variable

```
<script>
export default {

    data () {
      id: 0
    },
    props: ['propId'],
    methods: {
      init() { 
        this.id = this.propId  // step1. assign propId to id
      }
    },
    // add this to your code , this is a MUST. 
    // otherwise you won't SEE your data variable assigned by property
    watch { 
      propId: function(new_value) { 
        this.init()
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

## Step3. understand the process of rendering Child component

Assuming you have two component: `Parent` and `Child` ( `Child` has a property naming as `propId` ) , and `Child` also have a "async" operation such as reading database.

```
// Parent's View

<Child propId='parent_var_id'></Child>
```

3.1 `Parent` got rendered

3.2 `Child` got rendered , in this case, parent_var_id blank

3.3 `10ms` later, parent_var_id changed to `100`

3.4 `Child` property `propId` also changed as binding.

3.5 `Child` 's `watch` function called,  and the variable `id` defined in `data` changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
   {{messaged}}
   // other HTML code
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      props: ['messaged'],
      data: function(){
         return () {
           some_var: this.messaged
         }
      },
      methods: {
      post_order: function () {
        console.log({
          some_var: this.some_var.id
        })
      }
    }

   }
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain why your code is the correct answer.

Comment: because i tested it

Comment: Return won't have the brackets () after it.  As you have did `return () {
           some_var: this.messaged
         }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done your solution since the question posted a couple of month earlier. I faced the same problem yesterday, so tried out above solutions without no luck. However, I would like to share an alternative solution for this case that helps someone considerably.
`watch` has some attributes to handle those type of cases. Below scrips shows that how do we accept the props value is data.

```
<script>
   export default {
      props: {
            messageId: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
      data: function(){
         var theData= {
            somevar: "",
            // other object attributes
         }

         return theData;
      },
      watch: {
        messageId: {
                // Run as soon as the component loads
                immediate: true,
                handler() {
                    // Set the 'somevar' value as props
                    this.somevar = this.messageId;
                }
            }
      }
   }
</script>
```