# vue3 Transferring incoming data with props to another data

Tags: vuejs3

hello i am new among you,
I want to transfer the data from the props to the "items new" data, but it didn't work no matter what I did. is there a way to run this?

```
  {{ itemsnew }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ImageList',
  props: ['items'],
  data() {
    return {
      itemsnew: this.files(),
      dragging: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    files() {
      return this.items
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing props in vue component data function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722433/accessing-props-in-vue-component-data-function)

Comment: when I push an item it doesn't work

Comment: So you are able to access the props from inside the data function, but cannot modify the data? If so, please edit your question accordingly so we can more easily understand your problem.